# MVP and presenter granularity

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

We've been using the MVP pattern and Winforms with a fair amount of success. However, a question always pops-up about MVP:

What is a *good* granularity for presenters?

What I mean by that is: With Winforms, a fine-granularity usually works quite well for user controls. That way, it's easy to reuse user controls and use them as building blocks while designing more complex GUIs. However, having the same (fine-)granularity with presenters seems to be a problem.

On one hand, having **coarse-grained presenters** hinders the ability to use "plug-in" controls and it sorts of violate the DRY principle: Multiple presenters often need to implement the same logic (populate a list of customers, for instance), which is used by multiple, more complex, controls.

On the other hand, **fine-grained presenters** seem to limit the ability to reuse controls in different situations. For instance, an editing view might sometimes need to save the customer right away; sometimes it needs to link it to something else; sometimes is just needs to validate it; and so on. It often depends on the more complex control. But there's also a fair amount of shared behaviour.

Note that, in both cases, 1-presenter-1-view is achievable. What is considered "1-view" changes.

**What is usually considered best-practices for presenter granularity using MVP and Winforms?**

- Fine-grained presenters and *customizable* behaviour through options or something of that nature?
- Coarse-grained presenters and low presenter reusability?
- Something else?

Disclaimer: We mainly use Supervising Controller but I think it also applies to Passive View. Sorry for the long question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use MVP at all of our clients and this is definitely a conversation that comes up in more than one occasion. How clean should our code behind classes and presenters be? Having said that, we have chosen to use the coarse-grained presenter approach. Basically, every form would have its own presenter and would only get and set properties of any of the controls on a particular form using its view. Populating controls-a call to a db to populate a combobox for example-is located in a public service class. Any validation of user inputted data is located in a BO class which can be reused by any and/or all of the presenters. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my CAD-CAM system my presenters don't use user controls. User controls reside in the view which reside in a EXE assembly that implement the view interfaces the presenter use.

If want to display a list of customers I hand it off to the view which has a DisplayCustomerList and it uses whatever combination of user controls it needs to display the customer list. If multiple views show the customer list in the same way then in the ExE/View assembly they share a user control or class for doing that. That class doesn't go outside of that assembly.

Our software is adapted to run many different types of metal cutting machine. So we place a lot of emphasis on being able to rip off the UI and replace it with a completely different UI (corresponding to a different machine). All of these UIs reference the same set of core assemblies.

The hierarchy looks like this

View EXE
Presenter Implementation
Command Assembly - commands are executed by the presenter that modify the model
Presenter Interfaces
Model Assemblies

Off to the side are loadable assemblies that define dynamic content like what file types can be loaded, reports, cutting device drivers, etc. These implement various interfaces found in the model assemblies

One thing I do is that I don't impelment a view presenter for every dialog. If the dialog is tightly bound with a command then it is defined, created, and used along side the command class. Occasionally a group of related commands will share a dialog (File handling for example).

The essential question I ask when using MVP is "What happens if want to completely replace the forms with something else?". The answers to that question will identify where you are too dependent on a particular user control or form engine.

The biggest problem (and one that I haven't got a good answer for) of my setup is that current IDEs and langauges make it very easy to tie user controls to database records. It is so productive compared any other setup it tends to dominate the design. I haven't had to deal with the issue much in my CAD-CAM application so I don't have any answer other than passing the dataset to the view and let it handle it. [This site](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/) has some patterns that may be of use in this situation.

Comment: I understand presenters don't relate to any sort of user control directly. The dilemma is whether to have a lot of them talk to their own presenter or to have the end-form do all the "talking" for them. This was helpful nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: The only time I would do that if the User control or group of user controls form a complete view unto themselves. For example you have a tabbed UI and when you click on the different tab to switch between different views of the same data. In that case each tab would be a view related to the view that holds the form as a whole